# Warning: : DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in functions.php when adding classes to post images

Tags: functions, errors, html, warnings

So I'm using this code to add an extra class to all the images that load in the post and page content, and everything works good, but if there's no image I get the error also sometimes the error loads before loading the image.

This is the code

```
function add_img_post_class($content){
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));
    $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
       $existing_class = $img->getAttribute('class');
       $img->setAttribute('class',"$existing_class post-image lazy-load o-image");
    }
    $html = $document->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'add_img_post_class');
```

And the error seems to be on the 5th line:

```
$document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));
```

Comment: Also, I'm getting the error sometimes after saving content on the CMS, it will just take me out of the admin and show the error, but still saves all the content

Comment: On the pages that cause the error, can you find out what `utf8_decode($content)` is returning?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question, so I just realize that in the pages that I get the error is because there's not a featured image or any image inside the post, when I  get the error I just get my normal single page and where the featured image should appear it appears the warning because there's not an image.

Comment: I meant separate the `utf8_decode($content)` line out of the `loadHTML`, so do something like `$utfContent = utf8_decode($content); echo "Content =({$utfContent})"; $document->loadHTML($utfContent);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of the code that will avoid the warning by adding a simple check that will return `$content` unmodified if it's an empty string.

The original code adds `<html>` to the modified markup (check the page source), which we don't want. The code below fixes that too.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_add_img_post_class' );
function wpse_add_img_post_class( $content ) {
    // Bail if there is no content to work with.
    if ( ! $content ) {
        return $content;
    }

    // Create an instance of DOMDocument.
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();

    // Supress errors due to malformed HTML.
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17559716/3059883
    $libxml_previous_state = libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    // Populate $dom with $content, making sure to handle UTF-8.
    // Also, make sure that the doctype and HTML tags are not added to our
    // HTML fragment. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/3059883
    $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ),
          LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

    // Restore previous state of libxml_use_internal_errors() now that we're done.
    libxml_use_internal_errors( $libxml_previous_state );

    // Create an instance of DOMXpath.
    $xpath = new \DOMXpath( $dom );

    // Get images then loop through and add additional classes.
    $imgs = $xpath->query( "//img" );
    foreach ( $imgs as $img ) {
        $existing_class = $img->getAttribute( 'class' );
        $img->setAttribute( 'class', "{$existing_class} post-image lazy-load o-image" );
    }

    // Save and return updated HTML.
    $new_content = $dom->saveHTML();
    return $new_content;
}
```